# How do I stop csslint and jshint from linting my EJS in Atom?

Tags: ejs, atom-editor, jshint, csslint

I'm editing EJS files in Atom. I currently have linter-csslint and linter-jshint packages installed. Both seem to be recognising the .ejs files as .html and linting it as HTML.

This is what I see

[image]

How do I get the linters to ignore .ejs files? Or is there a EJS specific linter for Atom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore all `.ejs` files with a `.jshintignore` file (https://jshint.com/docs/cli/#ignoring-files). I've just added one myself to fix this same issue in Atom and it seems to have worked.

I created `~/.jshintignore` with the following content:

```
*.ejs
```

Worth noting that this affects anything else using jshint.

Answer (score 1):

Based on that photo, it appears that you installed the `language-ejs` package and it is taking precedence on identifying the language. The problem here is not actually the linters, but rather the `language-html` package.

In the scopes for [linter-csslint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-csslint/blob/master/lib/main.js#L74) and [linter-jshint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint/blob/master/lib/main.js#L105), we see that both will lint on `language-html` scopes. However, your file is in the `language-ejs` scope. What is happening here is that Atom should be locking the scope down to just `language-ejs`, but is instead mixing between that and `language-html`. The reason that `language-html` is also a scope here is seen [here](https://github.com/atom/language-html/blob/master/grammars/html.cson#L3).

So fixing this for yourself is actually pretty easy. You can open up the source code for the `language-html` package locally (should be in `~/.atom/packages/language-html/grammars/html.cson`) and remove the `ejs` line that I showed above. However, the better long term fix is to probably raise an issue on `language-html` that you do not believe `ejs` is within the grammar scope of `html`. Also, Atom should probably not be identifying files as having multiple grammar scopes, but that is a more difficult issue to pursue.

PR to fix this permanently is [here](https://github.com/atom/language-html/pull/220).

Comment: Thanks Matt, that makes sense. But language-html is a core package, I can't seem to get to it locally without going into Atom dev mode. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @BenMorgan No, you stated it correctly. The fix for just yourself is not a long term fix. I double checked and it does seem `ejs` should not be in the html scope. However, there does seem to be quite a bit of support in Atom for treating EJS like html. It looks like they treated EJS as html instead of using the `html.ejs`. I will PR.

Answer (score 0):

You could just go to the packages and disable that particular package.